# Getting null value instead of Id when using custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I call this action method using an ajax call:

```
[AuthorizeCheckCreator]
[HttpPost]
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
{
    // code....
    return Content("ok");
}
```

I have created a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` for checking permission of the user (I wanted to make sure whether the user is owner the record or not):

```
public class AuthorizeCheckCreatorAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public IRequest RequestService { get; set; }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RequestCheckUserViewModel request;
        if (httpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var ajaxId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetId>(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                                    .GetString(httpContext.Request.BinaryRead(httpContext.Request.ContentLength)));
            var currentId = ajaxId.Id;
            var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!isAuthorized) return false;
            requestBank = RequestService.GetUserId(Guid.Parse(currentId));
        }
        else
        {
            var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
            var currentId = rd.GetRequiredString("id");
            var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!isAuthorized) return false;
            requestBank = RequestService.GetUserId(Guid.Parse(currentId));
        }

        var result = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>() == request.UserId ||
                     httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin") ||
                     httpContext.User.IsInRole("BankResponsible") ||
                     httpContext.User.IsInRole("BankManager");
        return result;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // handling the unauthorized requests
    }
}

public class GetId
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

With this code in place I always get null value for `id` parameter. I'm sure the client side code works fine because when I remove `[AuthorizeCheckCreator]` from `Delete` action method, I get value of `id`.
Any idea?

**Update:**
Ajax call:

```
$('.btnDelete').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this);
    var requestId = btn.data("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/bank/request/delete',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: requestId }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            // code
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your method is a POST - are you adding the `id` as route data in the form tag?

Comment: Yes it's a POST, As I mentioned I use ajax call for sending the `id`.

Comment: Are you sending the `id` value in the ajax call. The code you have shown throws multiple errors so impossible to reproduce this.

Comment: I updated my question, One strange thing is that when I hard coded `id` inside `AuthorizeCheckCreatorAttribute` I can get the id value. for example: `var ajaxId = "27598f75-5d4e-e611-80da-001f29ecb1da";`   It seems that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetId>(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                                    .GetString(httpContext.Request.BinaryRead(httpContext.Request.ContentLength)));` does something wrong.

Comment: There are lots of things wrong :) I would first start by adjusting the ajax to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and change `data: JSON.stringify({ id: requestId }),` to `data: { id: requestId },`. Then in the attribute use `Guid currentId = httpContext.Request["id"];` which should solve that bit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks :)